# React + Redux-Observable + Typescript - Compilation, Argument Not Assignable Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, redux-observable

I am creating an app using React and Redux-Observable. I am new to this and I am trying to create an epic to execute the user login.

My epic is below:

```
export const loginUserEpic = (action$: ActionsObservable<Action>) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType<LoginAction>(LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_ACTION),
    switchMap((action: LoginAction) =>
      ajax({
        url,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: { email: action.payload.username, password: action.payload.password },
      }).pipe(
        map((response: AjaxResponse) => loginSuccess(response.response.token)),
        catchError((error: Error) => of(loginFailed(error))),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

The problema is that I am getting a Typescript error on this line: `ofType<LoginAction>(LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_ACTION)` saying this:

```
Argument of type '(source: Observable<LoginAction>) => Observable<LoginAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Action<any>, LoginAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<Action<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<LoginAction>'.
      Type 'Action<any>' is not assignable to type 'LoginAction'.
        Property 'payload' is missing in type 'Action<any>'.
```

My actions are here:

```
export enum LoginActionTypes {
  LOGIN_ACTION = 'login',
  LOGIN_SUCCESS_ACTION = 'login-sucesss',
  LOGIN_FAILED_ACTION = 'login-failed',
}

export interface LoginAction extends Action {
  type: LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_ACTION;
  payload: {
    username: string;
    password: string;
  };
}

export function login(username: string, password: string): LoginAction {
  return {
    type: LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_ACTION,
    payload: { username, password },
  };
}

export interface LoginSuccessAction extends Action {
  type: LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS_ACTION;
  payload: {
    loginToken: string;
  };
}

export function loginSuccess(loginToken: string): LoginSuccessAction {
  return {
    type: LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS_ACTION,
    payload: { loginToken },
  };
}

export interface LoginFailedAction extends Action {
  type: LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILED_ACTION;
  payload: {
    error: Error;
  };
}

export function loginFailed(error: Error): LoginFailedAction {
  return {
    type: LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILED_ACTION,
    payload: { error },
  };
}

export type LoginActions = LoginAction | LoginSuccessAction | LoginFailedAction;
```

How can I fix this without using `any` types on the Epic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ofType` operator offered by `redux-observable` is not the best way to discriminate union types. A much better way is to use the `isOfType` function provided by [`typesafe-actions`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions).

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { isOfType } from 'typesafe-actions';
```

First, let's tell TypeScript about the possible actions used in your application. Your action stream should not be defined as `ActionsObservable<Action>`, but as a stream of *your* actions: `ActionsObservable<LoginActions>`.

```
export const loginUserEpic = (action$: ActionsObservable<LoginActions>) =>
```

Now we can use the `isOfType` predicate together with the `filter` operator. Replace this:

```
ofType<LoginAction>(LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_ACTION)
```

with this:

```
filter(isOfType(LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_ACTION))
```

The action passed down the stream will be correctly recognized as `LoginAction`.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without using `typesafe-actions`?

Comment: The implementation is pretty simple and portable. You could probably copy-paste it to your project if you like. https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions/blob/2065bfaad8281c6a8d504f50f34af9c84f61f81a/src/is-of-type.ts#L15-L23

Comment: I ended up implementing the `typesafe-actions` method(s). And I really like it - my actions and reducers are suddenly much "cleaner".

Comment: Amazing this saved me after hours upon hours

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide for the details below for all the standard way of doing when using React, Redux and Redux-Observable.

I would suggest using  `typesafe-actions` library to achieve the types.

Some pseudo codes:

**Actions**

Instead of this

```
export interface LoginSuccessAction extends Action {
  type: LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS_ACTION;
  payload: {
    loginToken: string;
  };
}

export function loginSuccess(loginToken: string): LoginSuccessAction {
  return {
    type: LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS_ACTION,
    payload: { loginToken },
  };
}
```

use `typesafe-actions`, without interface

`actions/login/LoginActions.ts`

```
import { action } from "typesafe-actions"

export function loginSuccess(loginToken: string) {
  return action(LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS_ACTION, { loginToken });
}
```

`actions/login/LoginActionsModel.ts`

```
import * as LoginActions from "./LoginActions";
import { ActionCreator } from "typesafe-actions";

export type LoginActionCreator = ActionCreator<typeof LoginActions>
```

Then export out All Actions.

`actions/index.ts`

```
import { LoginActionCreator } from "./login/LoginActionModel";

export default type AllActions = LoginActionCreator
```

**Epics**

```
import { Epic } from "redux-observable";
import { isOfType } from "typesafe-actions";
import { filter } from "rxjs/operators";
```

```
export const loginUserEpic: Epic<AllActions> = (action$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isOfType((LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_ACTION))),
    switchMap((action: LoginAction) =>
      ajax({
        url,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: { email: action.payload.username, password: action.payload.password },
      }).pipe(
        map((response: AjaxResponse) => loginSuccess(response.response.token)),
        catchError((error: Error) => of(loginFailed(error))),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Where the Epics is from `redux-observable` library, AllActions are the actions that is input and output of the epics.

The types is as follows:

```
Epic<InputActions, OutputActions, Store>
Epic<Actions(Input&Output)>
```

In case you want to use store from redux, you need a RootState (from root reducer)

```
export const someEpic: Epic<AllActions, AllActions, RootState> = (action$, store$) 
=> action$.pipe(
  filter(isOfType(SOMETYPE)),
  mergeMap(action => {
    const a = store$.value.a;
    return someActions(a, action.payload.b);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript gives an error because you have set to `ActionsObservable` action generic a redux `Action` that is an interface with form of `{ type: string }`. So Typescript thinks that all the actions coming will have only type, but you are setting to `ofType` filtering operator another type of Action, even if it extends redux Action interface Typescript will require `bivarianceHack` to allow you pass anything that implements that interface. One of the simplest workarounds is to change `ActionsObservable<Action>` to `ActionsObservable<AnyAction>`, with `AnyAction` which is imported from redux.